# When I install an extension on Opencart4, iam not able to select the zip file containing theme, iam getting a popup like "localhost says"

Tags: opencart, extention-cli

When I install an extension on Opencart4, i get an error "Problem with reading JSON", when i tried to install the extension a 2nd try, the error says "File already exist". iam not able to select the zip file for upload , getting a popup like "localhost says" how to fix this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly elaborate more and share more details about theme and configured environment. It may help others to fix the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.